# I can no longer activate wireless on my laptop

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, network-manager

I had to reinstall Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on my HP Compaq nc8230.
Everything went fine, as before.
I did a restart based on "197 Updates", then while carrying the laptop, I pressed the key labeled `2`

[image]

After this the wireless LAN was deactivated and I'm not able to activate it anymore; not with the key and not with the option on the upper right corner of my desktop.
Now the sign looks like an empty triangle.

`iwconfig` tells me that my interface 'eth1' has an wlan extension, which I already knew it had, because I used it before.  But I have no clue how to activate it again...

Can anyone suggest a fix?

Comment: Your image link is broken, or requires authentication to view

Comment: right now fixxin tht, thank you... I can see it without authentication thought :/ sry for tht

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a problem very similar to this with my laptop. After a recent installation of Ubuntu, my wifi adapter just totally shut off for some reason. I fixed it by changing the bios settings back to default. Not sure what I did to it, but try there first. I was dual booting that the time, and the wifi worked under windows 7, so it may be a driver issue. Also check to see if you are in Airplane mode, ya I forgot about checking that once and was really annoyed for a few minutes. Hope you find an answer!

Comment: Ok, Im gonna look for the Bios and If tht wont work, I'll reinstall Ubuntu the 5th time :D

Comment: Oh jeez, this is 7 yrs ago, but I remember that restoring the BIOS settings to default did the job, despite there being 0 settings that my former me would connect to anything wifi related.
Maybe thats gonna help someone still somewhen...